# How to correctly redact PDF file using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, redaction

I am trying to redact PDF files using python, tried many libraries like pdfrw, pdfminner and even pyPDF2 but none them helped me to redact content of PDF properly because it turns out that the library is merging the PDF using layers & its placing my redaction box on top of the original layer. I can Even select the contents beneath my redaction box (see refer image). I tried to flattened them it did helped me but it turns out I cant even select or copy any contents or search any part.

Issue with PDF

[image: Issue with PDF]

So please suggest me how to correctly redact the contents inside a PDF.

This is what I want to achieve: the redacted part is no longer accessible but the rest of the file is

[image]

Comment: You would need to find the PDF elements that make up the information you want to redact and change them, not just paste elements on top.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more

Answer (score -1):

Finally I was able to redact the contents properly, all you have to do is to get stream of PDF data & found out the object 'TJ' ,'BT' and 'ET' then replace those text with a Null or with words you need to replace. After that you can create a box over it also